# LIbreoffice calc: how to calculate sum of values by category

Tags: worksheet-function, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I have a calc file with two sheets:
First have a two columns **Category** (drop down list) and **Value**, it is sort of log file. 
Second have **Category** (same drop down list  but each category used once) and **Total value**.
Is the any way to automatically update **Total value** for each category from second sheet when new entry is added in first sheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for [SUMIF](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Mathematical_Functions#SUMIF).  As an example, say this is Sheet1:

```
Category    Value 
a           1
b           2
c           3
a           4
b           5
c           6
```

And this is Sheet2:

```
Category    Total Value 
a
b
c
```

Then use this formula for the Total Value of Category "a":

```
=SUMIF(Sheet1.A$2:A$10,"="&A2,Sheet1.B$2:B$10)
```

Drag this formula down through the row of Category "c".  Now we have:

```
Category    Total Value 
a           5
b           7
c           9
```

If we add another row on Sheet1 with Category "a" and value 7, then Sheet2 changes to this:

```
Category    Total Value 
a           12
b           7
c           9
```